# C / Como trocar o for por um while?

Tags: c, for, while

Escreva a função imprime usando a estrutura de repetição while ao invés de for. Caso necessite posso editar e inserir todo o código.

---

```
void imprime(Ccc *p)
{
    Ccc *r;
    for (r = p; r!=NULL; r = r->proximo)
        printf("%c",r->caracter);
}
```

---

Completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ccc {
    char caracter;
    struct ccc *proximo;
} Ccc;

void imprime(Ccc *p)
{
    Ccc *r;
    for (r = p; r!=NULL; r = r->proximo)
        printf("%c",r->caracter);
}

void liberar_memoria(Ccc *p)
{
    Ccc *q, *r;
    q = p;
    while (q!=NULL) {
        r = q->proximo;
        free(q);
        q = r;
    }
}

main()
{
    Ccc *p1, *p2, *p3;

    p1=(Ccc *)malloc(sizeof(Ccc));
    p2=(Ccc *)malloc(sizeof(Ccc));
    p3=(Ccc *)malloc(sizeof(Ccc));

    if ((p1==NULL)||(p2==NULL)||(p3==NULL)) 
        return;

    p1->caracter='A';
    p1->proximo=p2;

    p2->caracter='L';
    p2->proximo=p3;

    p3->caracter='O';
    p3->proximo=NULL;

    imprime(p1);
    liberar_memoria(p1);
 }
```

Comment: Você entendeu o que o `for` está fazendo? Poderia descrever com palavras?

Comment: Sim,vou postar o código completo.

Comment: Mas a pergunta que eu fiz foi "Poderia descrever com palavras o que você entendeu sobre a função do `for` nesse código", não "por favor, poste o código completo", embora possivelmente será melhor com o código completo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença entre o for e o while, é que o for permite que se faça atribuição e declaração de variáveis somente dentro daquele escopo, então o for irá realizar tanto a verificação da condição como a atualização do "indicador" automaticamente, não sendo necessário colocar dentro do escopo

Já o while só irá verificar uma condição simples e já irá para o escopo, então qualquer atribuição ou declaração de variável deve ser feita depois do formato

```
while (condição){ 
   (escopo);
}
```

entao seu codigo será:

```
 void imprime(Ccc *p){
    Ccc *r;
    r = p;
    while(r!=NULL;){
      printf("%c",r->caracter);
      r = r->proximo;
    }
 }
```

Comment: acho que seu código responde a pergunta, sim; só uma observação de que é possível tanto usar variáveis de escopo _"extra for"_ quanto apenas no escopo _"dentro do while"_, mas isso seria outra discussão :P de qualquer forma, existem várias leituras interessantes sobre escopo de variáveis, [como esta](http://linguagemc.com.br/funcoes-e-escopo-de-variaveis/)

Comment: Correto! só o ponto e virgula depois do NULL que acusou erro, removi e tudo certo while(r!=NULL;)...